# Pyinstaller: Twilio package

Tags: python, twilio, pyinstaller, packing, auto-py-to-exe

Does someone get this error packing py project with twilio?

"No module named 'twilio' [19300] Failed to execute script 'pcONpcesc' due to unhandled exception!"

If i execute de py script with sublimetext "for example" it works fine.

Sends email, whatsapp and mqtt without any issue.

I tried already with venv and also without virtual environment. Tried Pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe. The same error.

Tried: "pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import twilio.rest pcONpcesc.py"

Why is twilio not included?

Finally i find the twilio library on requirements.txt.

Code:

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
import random
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client
from twilio.rest import Client
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from datetime import date
from pytz import timezone


data_e_hora_atuais = datetime.now()
fuso_horario = timezone("Portugal")
data_e_hora_portugal = data_e_hora_atuais.astimezone(fuso_horario)
data_e_hora_portugal_em_texto = data_e_hora_portugal.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
global str_data
str_data = data_e_hora_portugal_em_texto


assunto = "PC - INFO"
mensagem = f"PC ESCR [DSK-FDESK] acabou de ser ligado. {str_data}"
para = "xxx@xxx.com"


def email_alerta(subject, body, to):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(body)
    msg["subject"] = subject
    msg["to"] = to

    user = "user@mail.com"
    password = "1234567887654321"

    msg["from"] = user

    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(user, password)
    server.send_message(msg)

    server.quit()

email_alerta(assunto, mensagem, para)

broker = "broker.emqx.io"
port = 8083
topic = "GERAL/TESTE1"

client_id = f"python-mqtt-{random.randint(0, 1000)}"
username = "userabc"
password = "pass1234"

msg1 = mensagem


def enviamqtt():
    def connect_mqtt():
        def on_connect(client_id, userdata, flags, rc):
            if rc == 0:
                print("Connectado ao MQTT Broker!")
            else:
                print("Falha na conexão, retornou o codigo %d\n", rc)

        client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id)
        client.subscribe(topic)
        client.username_pw_set(username, password)
        client.on_connect = on_connect
        client.connect(broker, port)
        return client

    connect_mqtt()

    def publish1(client):

        result = client.publish(topic, msg1)
        result: [0, 1]
        status = result[0]
        if status == 0:
            print(f"Enviado {msg1} para o topico {topic}")
        else:
            print(f"Falha ao enviar mensagem para o topico {topic}")

    client = connect_mqtt()
    publish1(client)

enviamqtt()

account_sid = "accountid"
auth_token = "tokengenerated"
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(from_="whatsapp:+141999900000", body=mensagem, to="whatsapp:+mynumber")

print(message.sid)
```

Comment: `pyinstaller` is not ideal tool and sometimes it can't find what modules it has to append and you have to manually add `twilio` to special file `.spec`. You should find information about file `spec` in `pyinstaller` documentation

Comment: you append `twilio.rest` but it may need full `twilio` to work correctly. So you may need `--hidden-import twilio` instead of `--hidden-import twilio.rest`

Comment: Thank you so much! @furas
I had tried to add the complete package but it didn't work.
I'll check the pyinstaller documentation. It's strange because the other packages are imported successfully. 
I also tested it with wscript. I created a file with a .vbs extension and it works perfectly!

Here the vbs script:

SecondsToDelay = 1
PythonExecutable = "C:\PYTHON\python.exe"
ScriptToRun = "D:\Temp\pcONpcesc.py"

WScript.Sleep SecondsToDelay * 1000

Command = Chr(34) & PythonExecutable & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & ScriptToRun & Chr(34)
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run Command

Comment: you have to test VB script on computer without Python. This script uses full path to Python `C:\PYTHON\python.exe` so it uses original Python with installed `twilio`. It may not work on computer with preinstalled Python. But `pyinstaller` tries to put all needed modules (and `Python.exe`) to `one ZIP file` (or `one folder`) and later it uses only modules in this `ZIP file` (or folder) - it doesn't uses original Python with installed `twilio`. You may also try to create `one folder` instead of `one file` and you will see if it put `twilio` in this folder.

Comment: Good news! I don´t know how and why but i test with .spec and it works! I´ve tested already in 2 pc´s without python installed and it works fine.
I think it was the special file .spec that @furas wrote at the first comment. The exe file increase a lot the size, but i didn´t change anything in this .spec file... 

Thanks a lot! It works! Awesome!

Comment: better show `spec` in question, not in comments. It will be more readable, and more people will see it - so more people may help you.